# Delphi reading non-text file (binary)

Tags: delphi, file-io

how in Delphi could I open binary file in non-text mode?
Like C function `fopen(filename,"rb")`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a few options.

**1. Use a file stream**

```
var
  Stream: TFileStream;
  Value: Integer;
....
Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
try
  Stream.ReadBuffer(Value, SizeOf(Value));//read a 4 byte integer
finally
  Stream.Free;
end;
```

**2. Use a reader**

You would combine the above approach with a `TBinaryReader` to make the reading of the values simpler:

```
var
  Stream: TFileStream;
  Reader: TBinaryReader;
  Value: Integer;
....
Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
try
  Reader := TBinaryReader.Create(Stream);
  try
    Value := Reader.ReadInteger;
  finally
    Reader.Free;
  end;
finally
  Stream.Free;
end;
```

The reader class has lots of functions to read other data types. And you can go in the opposite direction with a binary writer.

**3. Old style Pascal I/O**

You can declare a variable of type `File` and use `AssignFile`, `BlockRead`, etc. to read from the file. I really don't recommend this approach. Modern code and libraries almost invariably prefer the stream idiom and by doing the same yourself you'll make your code easier to fit with other libraries.

Comment: Now I see where is the difference. Variable of type File and TextFile. Thanks you all.

Comment: Don't forget the `FileOpen()`, `FileRead()`, and `FileClose()` functions, which are what `TFileStream` uses internally.

Comment: TFileCreate.Create ?

Comment: @eduado thanks silly typo. You would have been welcome to edit.

Answer (score 3):

You have different options, two of them are:

Use the *old school* approach, like the C function you pointed out:

```
var
  F: File;
begin
  AssignFile(F, 'c:\some\path\to\file');
  ReSet(F);
  try
    //work with the file
  finally
    CloseFile(F);
  end
end;
```

Use a more modern approach to create a TFileStream based on the file:

```
var
  F: TFileStream;
begin
  F := TFileStream.Create('c:\some\path\to\file', fmOpenRead);
  try
    //work with the file
  finally
    F.Free;
  end;
```